# How ro declare a member which is a pointer to function

Tags: c++

```
#define SYNC_DATA_CB list<string> (*syncData)(void)
```

I want to have in my class a member (static or not is not matter) that will hold the reference to the function pointer.

I tried to declare like this, but didnt compiled:

```
SyncProcess{
  public:
   SyncProcess(SYNC_DATA_CB);
   static SYNC_DATA_CB sync_cb_;
}
```

Comment: This is not even close to C; please tag your questions only with the languages they apply to. Also you are not declaring the  class correctly at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you might be looking for is a typedef instead.

```
typedef list<string>(*syncData)(void);

class SyncProcess{
  public:
   SyncProcess( syncData );
   static syncData sync_cb_;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::function<list<string> (void)> myPointer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use typedef instead of macro:

```
class SyncProcess
{
public:    

   // Typedef to create function pointer alias SyncDataFunc
   typedef list<string>(*SyncDataFunc)();

   // Use alias as input parameter type
   SyncProcess(SyncDataFunc func);

   // Use alias as static member type
   static SyncDataFunc sync_cb_;
};
```